eslint 8.47 ignores everything
I have a basic vitejs project and am trying to get eslint working. I have these relevant files:
.eslintrc.js :
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['react-refresh'],
  rules: {
    'react-refresh/only-export-components': [
      'warn',
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
  },
}

eslint.config.js:
import js from "@eslint/js";

export default [
    js.configs.recommended,

   {
       rules: {
           "no-unused-vars": "warn",
           "no-undef": "warn"
       }
   }
];

...but as soon as I run the cli command it gives me errors about ignored files:
>  npx eslint ./src/*.ts

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.57.0

You are linting "./src/*.ts", but all of the files matching the glob pattern "./src/*.ts" are ignored.

If you don't want to lint these files, remove the pattern "./src/*.ts" from the list of arguments passed to ESLint.

If you do want to lint these files, try the following solutions:

* Check your .eslintignore file, or the eslintIgnore property in package.json, to ensure that the files are not configured to be ignored.
* Explicitly list the files from this glob that you'd like to lint on the command-line, rather than providing a glob as an argument.


there is no .eslintignore file of eslintIgnore property in my package.json

So I tried linting just one file App.tsx :
> npx eslint ./src/App.tsx

C:\current-projects\eslint-test\vite-project\src\App.tsx
  0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to disable file ignore settings or use "--no-warn-ignored" to suppress this warning

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

... after which I tried using the --no-ignore parameter, but that just gave the same response.
Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Why is eslint so bent on ignoring every file I throw at it?
